# Unique button for each row in a table?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a table populated with data from a database. Each row in the table needs to have a button on the end which has a query string identifying the "artist"'s name and needs to link to content specific to that individual artist. With my current table, the buttons are just repeated and are not individual, and I don't know how to make them query the artist they pertain to.

```
  <?php


//Query to get artist data
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM artist LIMIT 10");
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
   
      
      
      
      //show artist data in table
       echo "<table><th>BadNoise Artists</th>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td><td><button>Get External Content</button></td></tr>" ;
          }
 echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close($con);

    

    
    
?>
```

I'm using jQuery to populate the div which will show the content specific to each artist:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want see the artit's details? in a modal, in a new page?

Comment: The artists details (FirstName, LastName) appear in the table on the same page as you can see in the code above, when a button is clicked. I then need a button at the end of each row which will populate a div (one div for each artist) with content related to that artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. Store the artist's ID in the ID field of the button and obtain it via Jquery:

```
<?php

//Query to get artist data
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM artist LIMIT 10");
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}

//show artist data in table
echo "<table><th>BadNoise Artists</th>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td><td><button id='" . $row['artistId'] . "'>Get External Content</button></td></tr>" ;
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

?> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var artistId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#div1").load("demo_test" + artistId + ".txt");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, but, from having a look at it, it seems it will always populate the div "div1". I need to have a different div populated depending on which artist's button has been clicked (each artist has their own div).

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work.. nothing happens when I click the button. I'm thinking "ArtistNumber" in the script probably isn't recognised?

  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test" + ArtistNumber + ".txt");
  });
});
</script>`


 `{
          echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td><td><button id='" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "'>Get External Content</button></tr>" ;`

Comment: Sorry, I have also added `var ArtistNumber = $(this).attr('id');` but this is now displaying a text file for each button that doesn't even exist any more!

Comment: Ok, a quick re-boot has obviously cleared the caches and this is working! Thank you. Is there a way for each artist to have their own div rather than for every button to populate the same div?